# SymmetricDS system tables on a different schema other than public

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

Is there a way to have SymmetricDS system tables to be put on any other schema say 'replication' other than the default "Public" schema in PostgreSQL? 
I don't want to mix the symmetric system tables with my tables that is present in the Public Schema.

SymmetricDS version 2.5
PostgreSQL 9.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just add a user say "symmetricds" and make the replication schema as the users default search_path